# If I visit someone’s island in acnh, do villagers talk about them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

So, I know that if somebody visits my island the villagers will talk about that person to me for a while, but is it the same if I visit someone else’s island? Will my villagers talk about me going to someone’s island?

Answer (score 1):

> I know that if somebody visits my island the villagers will talk about that person to me
>
> is it the same if I visit someone else’s island?

Logically, the answer could only be be either "yes" or "no, you are the only player for which this happens". Obviously, the answer is **yes**.

> Will my villagers talk about me going to someone’s island?

I have not encountered this type of conversation so far.

Comment: it does happen, if you visit an island, or someone visits yours.